# Seaborn Catplot bar colours

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm looking to make all of the bars in my catplot the same color however I can't find any way to override this. I find Seaborn lacking in any comprehensive documentation. The code I have is:

```
g = sns.catplot(kind = 'bar', data = data, x = 'Tenant Age Range', y = 'Difference to Office Average Arrears in Age Range', 
                    col = 'LHO Name', col_wrap = 4, palette = 'pastel', color= '#abc9ea')
g.set_ylabels("Diff. to Citywide Arrears Average (£)")
    
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

The following image shows a section of the resultant plot. I want only blue bars with the hex colour '#abc9ea'

[image: Catplot with different colours of bars]

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Also if someone could point me in the direction of a decent learning resource for seaborn that would be really helpful.

Many thanks
Andy

Comment: Remove `palette = 'pastel'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `palette` parameter when calling `sns.catplot()`. Here is the corrected code:

```
g = sns.catplot(kind = 'bar', data = data, x = 'Tenant Age Range', y = 'Difference to Office Average Arrears in Age Range', col = 'LHO Name', col_wrap = 4, color= '#abc9ea')
```